# How to get random positions of elements with different values in a python list?

Tags: python, random

Suppose a python list, for instance:`l = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4]` (not necessarily the list is sorted).

I would like to randomly select positions of `n` different elements within the list.

For instance, suppose that `n=3`, so I would like to select the positions of three different elements in the list.

A solution is: positions 0,4,8 respectively related to three different elements values 1,2,4.

What is the most efficient way to do this in Python?

Comment: How do you want the randomness to be distributed?  For example, if you have `[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]` and you select with `n=1`, should all indices be equally likely, or should you expect the answer to be 0 half the time?

Comment: See [How much research?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  Various random selection methods are covered in the documentation of the `random` package.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to shuffle the list and get the values in order.

```
import random

l = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4]
random.shuffle(l)


n = 3
arr = []
for i in range(n):
    arr.append(i)
```

Comment: How does this guarantee that the indices correspond to different values?

Comment: I need to choose indexes not the values.

Comment: Ok. Then ignore this answer

Answer (score 0):

You want random indexes from a list?  Use the `sample` method over a range.

```
import random

l = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4]
n = 3

random.sample(range(len(l)), n)
```

Comment: Indexes should be selected based on the  their respective values.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `value : indices` dictionary, where the `value` is a unique value from the list `l`, and `indices` is the list of the indices of `value` in `l`. You can then get a random index from the `indices` list of each `value` of the `n` randomly selected unique values:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from random import sample, choice

index_map = defaultdict(list)

for i, v in enumerate(l):
    index_map[v].append(i)

n = 3

# choose `n` random unique values from `l`
rand_values = sample(list(index_map), n)

# choose a random index of each of the `n` random values
rand_indices = [choice(index_map[v]) for v in rand_values]

print(rand_indices)
```

Comment: Your answer is accurate. I'm thinking about whether is possible to do this generating only 3 random numbers. In your answers, it is generated 6 random numbers: 3 random numbers to obtain 3 values (in 'sample' function), and 3 random numbers for getting positions (3 calls of 'choice' function).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by first create a new list with each value only once, then random values from it.

try it:

```
l = list(set([1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4]))
```

now you can use the methods that appears here, to get n random elements fron the list, and you can know that you'll get diffrence values

Comment: Indexes should be selected based on the their respective values. I need to choose indexes not the values.

Comment: so after you can find the index of each value, but it start to be comlex. you can instead use a simple while loop to get random indexes and check if them value was choosed, until you'll get enough indexes. I can put you this code if you interested